# vba xlsm crashes- shared file on two desktops

Tags: excel, runtime, paste, vba

Runtime error 2147417848-80010108
Method paste of object worksheet failed.

This error started to occur when i opened the file simultaneously on two desktops. Then it occurs every time i run the code.
The code is really big so cant paste it here. 
I eill only paste the lines in which the problem occurs

```
rrr=4
set rng1 = worksheets(2).range("x1:cd1").find(format(date,,xlvalues,xlwhole)
If not rng1 is nothing then
Worksheets("--").activate
Worksheets("--").cells(rrr,rng1.column).select
Activesheet.paste
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically try to avoid copy/paste. Instead, see if assigning the value directly works.

```
Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range
Set copyRng = ' Your copy range here
Set pasteRng = Worksheets("--").Cells(rrr, rng1.Column)

pasteRng = copyRng.Value
```

Copy/paste generally has performance issues, especially when used with large amounts of data.